# Pass queue name in mapreduce job via command line

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can we pass the queue name in mapreduce job while running via command line. I have tried passing it as :

```
set -e; export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST='true';export HADOOP_OPTS='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp'; export HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/path/to/jars-1.0.jar';sudo -E -u myUser hadoop jar /path/to/jar  com.pacakage.ClassName -D mapred.job.queue.name=prod_queue --input {inputPath} --output {outputPath}
```

Also tried to set the mapred.job.queue.name as :

```
set -e; export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST='true';export HADOOP_OPTS='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp'; export HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/path/to/jars-1.0.jar';set mapred.job.queue.name=prod_queue;sudo -E -u myUser hadoop jar /path/to/jar  com.pacakage.ClassName  --input {inputPath} --output {outputPath}
```

None of the above command is working and the error I am getting is :

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_xxxxx to YARN : Application application_xxxxx submitted by user myUser to unknown queue: default

Comment: think the correct name of the property is `mapreduce.job.queuename`. Also, you don't need a space between `-D` and property name.

Comment: nope, tried that variation as well. its not working

Answer (score 0):

After Hadoop 2.4.1 property name is `mapreduce.job.queuename`.

If it still does not work via command line you can try to set property directly in job:
`job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename", queue);`